# How to hide keyboard with programmatically created uitextfield

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I've programmatically created a uitextfield called "myTextField" in "viewDidLoad".

When I create a function to hide the keyboard when the user taps anywhere on the screen, "myTextField" isn't recognized by xcode. Is it because the textfield is created inside "viewDidLoad"?
Is there any way to access and use "myTextField" outside "viewDidLoad"?

Update: I finally had a chance to go home and copy my code to show what I mean. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Prepare keyboard notifications
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil);


    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height;
    let myTextView : UITextField = UITextField(
        frame : CGRect(x:10, y:(screenHeight/2), width:(screenWidth-20), height: (screenHeight/3) ) )
    myTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor( red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue:0, alpha: 1.0 )
        self.scrollView.addSubview( myTextView )
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.

func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    let dict:NSDictionary = sender.userInfo as NSDictionary
    let s:NSValue = dict.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as NSValue;
    let rect :CGRect = s.CGRectValue();
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height)

}
   func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {

   let dict:NSDictionary = sender.userInfo as NSDictionary
   let s:NSValue = dict.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey) as NSValue;
  let rect :CGRect = s.CGRectValue();
  self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

 }
```

I've created a UITextView programmatically because I'm struggling with auto layout in Xcode 6. In the meantime I've updated to Xcode beta 5 (from 4) and now even my scrollview is acting weird. So maybe I have to create it with code as well.

How can I access my textview outside of function viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as a property of that class, then you can access it from anywhere. Otherwise its scope is limited to the viewDidLoad function and you can't access it from outside.

```
class YourClass {

    var myTextField:UITextField

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //init myTextField
    }  

    func test() {
       //do something with myTextField
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't have any luck with your approach so I went home and copied the code I've created. I've updated the original message.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one to dismiss keyboard :-

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("resignFirstResponder", to:nil, from:nil, forEvent:nil)
```